# Why isn't networkx drawing edges?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to create a visual graph with networkx, but the edges aren't showing up. The nodes are there, but the edges either don't display or are extremely incorrect. I've looked at other posts, but none seem to have an answer.

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx


def create_graph(filename, path):
    pos = {}
    G = nx.Graph()
    for index in range(0, len(path2)-1):
        pos[index] = (path[index][0], path[index][1])
    for index in range(0, len(path)-2):
        G.add_edge(index, index+1)
    print(G.edges())
    G.add_nodes_from(pos.keys())
    print(G.nodes())
    nx.draw(G, pos, node_color = 'b')

    name = filename.split('.')
    pic_name = name[0] + ".png"
    plt.savefig(pic_name)
```

My original program doesn't produce any edges, but a simple test program does.

```py
import graphing

list = [[32.4, 15.15],[12.5, 37.3],[236.3, 62.37],[235.3, 26.46],[324.27, 346.2],[25.45, 344.3],[34.23, 63.3]]

graphing.create_graph("test",list)
```

You can criticize all the other things I'm doing wrong, but I'm primarily concerned with why edges don't work some of the time. Is there anything obviously wrong with my approach?

Edit:
After printing the path as well the output for the Djibouti data is:

```
[['22583.3333', '14300.0000'], ['21600.0000', '14150.0000'], ['21600.0000', '14966.6667'], ['21600.0000', '16500.0000'], ['20900.0000', '17066.6667'], ['20833.3333', '17100.0000'], ['23616.6667', '15866.6667'], ['23700.0000', '15933.3333'], ['23883.3333', '14533.3333'], ['24166.6667', '13250.0000'], ['25149.1667', '12365.8333'], ['26283.3333', '12766.6667'], ['26433.3333', '13433.3333'], ['26550.0000', '13850.0000'], ['27096.1111', '13415.8333'], ['27153.6111', '13203.3333'], ['27026.1111', '13051.9444'], ['27462.5000', '12992.2222'], ['27433.3333', '12400.0000'], ['27233.3333', '11783.3333'], ['26733.3333', '11683.3333'], ['26150.0000', '10550.0000'], ['27233.3333', '10450.0000'], ['27266.6667', '10383.3333'], ['27166.6667', '9833.3333'], ['26133.3333', '14500.0000'], ['22683.3333', '12716.6667'], ['22183.3333', '13133.3333'], ['21300.0000', '13016.6667'], ['22583.3333', '14300.0000']]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 14), (14, 15), (15, 16), (16, 17), (17, 18), (18, 19), (19, 20), (20, 21), (21, 22), (22, 23), (23, 24), (24, 25), (25, 26), (26, 27), (27, 28)]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  I suspect the issue is something with the inputs.  Can you tell us what input doesn't produce edges, and what input does?

Comment: The original program is passing a list of lists, similar to the test program, but with many more nodes. Basically, it's a travelling salesman problem being solved using the nearest neighbor algorithm. Once it has the best solution, it attempts to graph it. When attempting to use the data set (provided by the University of Waterloo) from Djibouti, the graph seems to display the nodes correctly, but has no edges. When I use the data for Western Sahara and Qatar, the edges are insanely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Original:

```
pos[index] = (path[index][0], path[index][1])
```

It turns out that I needed to cast the values as floats.

Fixed:

```
pos[index] = (float(path[index][0]), float(path[index][1]))
```